# How do I scan a sentence in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have a text file which has three lines:

> apple man woman
>   pear
>   banana

I used

```
char name[100];
fgets(name,100,inputfile)
```

So now `name` should be "apple man woman"`. All three words separates by blank spaces, right?

I want to put these three words in a single `array`.

I think I need to use `fgets` but I'm new to C language and I don't know how.
Can someone give me an example on how to store this?

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How+do+I+scan+a+sentence+in+C) are 350 000 000 examples

Comment: Try googling this kind of stuff. It will be faster than the response that you will get here or follow @Ben's suggestion.

Comment: "So now name should be "apple man woman"" --> almost.  It likely will be `"apple man woman\n"`  `name` has a trailing `'\n'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char name[] = "apple man woman";
    char *array[sizeof(name)/2];

    int n = 0;
    for(char *word = strtok(name, " \t\n"); word; word = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")){
        array[n++] = word;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        puts(array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```